# Locust master process gets killed due to out of memory

Tags: python, python-2.7, load-testing, greenlets, locust

Having a Locust master and slave setup with 8 slaves running om  8 AWS instances with 4 GB RAM and 64bit Ubuntu. ON setting the number of users to 500 and and hatch rate to 200 i see master process gets killed with-in 15 mins. MIN_WAIT & MAX_WAIT are set to 10 and 100 respectively.
i see locust master almost consumes around 3 gb of memory.
why does locust requires such huge memory. how to fix this issue and run load test for long time. for about 100 hrs. i want to achieve RPS of around 3000 with locust.

Comment: If this is the case, then it's definitely a bug. How would I go about to reproduce this?

Comment: One possibility I can think of, is if you are doing a lot of requests to unique URLs (e.g. URLs containing different IDs) without grouping them (http://docs.locust.io/en/latest/writing-a-locustfile.html#grouping-requests-to-urls-with-dynamic-parameters).

If that doesn't solve it, perhaps you could post the test script that you're using, since that's where the issue most likely is?

Comment: this is has helped me to solve the issue thanks for your response

Comment: How did this issue get solved?i too facing same problem. I am doing a lot of requests to unique URL.

Comment: Please refer https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/writing-a-locustfile.html#grouping-requests-to-urls-with-dynamic-parameters this will help to resolve